# Слайдер уплывает вправо

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться, почему слайдер уплывает направо в Мозиле?
Тут расположен сам слайдер http://spfireworks.16mb.com/
А это css файлы к нему: http://spfireworks.16mb.com/css/style.css и http://spfireworks.16mb.com/css/style_alt.css
П.с. я поставил теги <br>, чтобы подкатить верхнее меню и слайдер, все подошло, но только в Файрфоксе проблема вот такая, и если можно как-то соединить три блока вместе(меню,слайдер и корзина), подскажите как, заранее спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

`.jms-slideshow` - сюда добавить `clear: left;`

У вас верхнее меню флотнутое, и оно тащит за собой слайдер.

Либо же с меню убрать `float: left`, оно там не нужно, и добавить `overflow: hidden;` на него. Так как в средине есть float элементы. Так будет правильно!